# Selenium and PhantomJS code examples that use directory path as opposed to using a URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium, phantomjs, automated-tests, ui-testing

Here are the details of my Development Environment:

•Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 4

•Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

•Selenium Chrome Driver Win 32 2.12

•Windows 7 Professional with 32-bit Operating System

Phantom JS 1.9.8

•NUnit 2.6.3

One of our Customers wanted us to create Test Harness Webpages that we can use to test various UI components of our web application.

The Test Harness should be Simple Webpage where we can test the ViewPanel of the web application or the Footer for the Web application.

It's the components like the ViewPanel or the footer that could be complex, but the Test Harness WebPage should be simple.   Think of the Test Harness as an Isolated Science Laboratory area.  We could have a Test Harness dedicated to testing a ViewPanel of the web application.  Another Test Harness dedicated to testing a Footer of the web application.

In our Test Harness Webpage design, we load the "UI component Under Test" into the Test Harness Webpage by specifying the directory path ( relative path or absolute path ) that leads to the "UI component Under Test"

For example, our Test Harness Webpage code will specify a directory path ( relative path or absolute path ) like the following:

```
D:\WrkSpce\BlahBlahApplicationProjectBlahBlah\MainSection\BlahBlahSidePanelBlahBlah.aspx

or

\MainSection\BlahBlahFooterBlahBlah.cshtml
```

Therefore, our Test Harness Webpage does Not use a URL to locate the "UI component Under Test", but rather a directory path ( relative path or absolute path ) within the computer system.

The problem is that most Selenium and PhantomJS code examples show the "component Under Test" being tested by using a URL.  For example,

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");

IWebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"..\..\SeleniumConfigFiles"), options);

Uri  url = new Uri("http://localhost:2816/");    // Notice the URL being Used
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.00));
```

Our team was interested in integrating Selenium and/or PhantomJS technology into the Test Harness Webpages

However, Most Selenium and PhantomJS code examples show the "component Under Test" being tested by using a URL.  Our Test Harness Webpage loads the "UI component Under Test" by specifying the directory path ( relative path or absolute path ).

Could someone please show some Selenium and PhantomJS code examples that show the "component Under Test"  being loaded by specifying the directory path ( relative path or absolute path )  within the computer system as opposed to using a URL ?

**Update**

@artjom-b ,   Thanks for responding to my question.

Let's say I have the following cshtml that I want test with Selenium

file:///D:/WrkSpce/blahBlahApplicationProjBlah/Views/Index.cshtml

You mentioned in your comment that the above path would Fail to work with Selenium because CSHTML file are Not by and in themselves rendered files.

You mentioned that I would need to write a mapper from file path to URL.

However, is Not the following already considered as a URL:

file:///D:/WrkSpce/blahBlahApplicationProjBlah/Views/Index.cshtml

Could you please tell me how I would rewrite the above as a URL so that it will work properly with Selenium?

Comment: Local html files can be loaded with the `file:///path` syntax, but that won't help you as this only works for rendered html which cshtml is not. You will need to write a mapper from file path to URL.

Comment: Thx for responding. Could you please see my update to the question?

Comment: Yes, `file:///D:/WrkSpce/blahBlahApplicationProjBlah/Views/Index.cshtml` is a valid URL, but if you would load it in PhantomJS, it wouldn't be understood, because a cshtml file is a template and not the output that you want after the template is applied. This is only accessible through localhost.

Comment: Ok, I believe you are saying that it needs to go through a server because it needs to get rendered, and then on can Selenium work with it.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I can't help you there. I have no idea how routing works in asp.net, because I never used it. I just wanted give you the idea what has to be done so that you can clarify that in your question.